# A "contraction" on tensor product spaces

Tags: reference-request, tensor-products

Let $X$ be a topological vector space. Let $X'$ denote its continuous dual. Consider the (algebraic) tensor product $\mathbb{X} := X \otimes X'$. For simple tensors $x \otimes x' \in \mathbb{X}$ set $T(x \otimes x') := x'(x)$ and extend by linearity. Does $T$ have an established name?

Comment: Yes, take away the quote from "contraction".

Comment: @guestDiego: ay, thx.

Comment: @guestDiego: In line with [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23417/66081) I propose that you post an brief answer...